How prevent RecyclerView from overwriting the view beneath it?
This is my layout:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ScannerFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/saleList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cameraPreview"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_widget"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/filler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/saleList"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/total_widget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

And this is what it looks like:

Please look at the bottom of the image were the item from the RecyclerView is overwriting the 'Total' text. I want the RecyclerView to expand no further than to the top of the 'Total' text.
The catch is that I want the 'Total' text to stick to the bottom above the ad even if the RecyclerView is empty. Thus I cannot simply constrain it that way.
I tried various constraints with the 'filler' View, but that did not work properly either. In some cases the items added to the RecyclerView made the RecyclerView expand from the middle between the CameraPreview and the 'Total' text. Only to finally overwrite both the CameraPreview and the 'Total' text...
Is there a conscious way to achieve the layout I want without fiddling around with it endlessly?
EDIT:
Adding app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_widget" to the RecyclerView has undesired effects: The RecyclerView pops up in the middle between the CameraPreview and total_widget once it is populated:

I want the items to appear right under the CameraPreview. The second problem is that once the list in the RecyclerView is growing it overwrites not just the total_widget, but also the CameraPreview:


Try setting height of the RecyclerView to 0dp (follow constraints).

The problem in the original code lies in the layout_height attributes of the root layout(LinearLayout), ConstraintLayout, and RecyclerView elements.
In the original code:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ScannerFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/saleList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cameraPreview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_widget"/>

The ConstraintLayout has a layout_height set to wrap_content, and the RecyclerView inside it also has a layout_height set to wrap_content. This can lead to unexpected behavior, especially when dealing with scrolling content like RecyclerViews.
In the fixed code:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ScannerFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/saleList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cameraPreview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_widget" />

The layout_height of both the ConstraintLayout and RecyclerView elements are set to 0dp, with the ConstraintLayout having a layout_weight of 1. This ensures that the RecyclerView will expand to fill the available vertical space within the ConstraintLayout, which is a more appropriate setup for a scrolling list.
Key takeaways:

When using ConstraintLayout as a parent layout, avoid using
wrap_content for dimensions, especially for views that contain
scrolling content like RecyclerViews.
Instead, use 0dp (match    constraints) combined with layout_weight
to properly allocate space    within ConstraintLayouts, allowing
views to expand or fill available    space as needed.
Always consider the behavior of scrolling content    and make sure it
has enough space to display its contents without    being constrained
by the parent layout's dimensions.


That doesn't work. There is nothing visible once I start adding items to the RecyclerView. Adding weight to the RecyclerView doesn't help. Furthermore, the 'Total' text is stuck right below the CameraPreview, instead of right above the ad.

Have a look : https://gist.github.com/Dhruv-Limbachiya/7acc68657a2cd81d430fdc02c2b11c33

Thank you very much for the effort. That does work as I intend it to. Could you please edit your answer to explain why this works? What is the important take away?

Edited the answer. I've not mentioned PreviewView intentionally as it fills the available and required vertical space within the ConstraintLayout like RecyclerView

Couple of things:

Recyclerviews have scroll built in.  No need to put it in a ScrollView.

Add a constraintBottom_toTopOf to the RecyclerView (after you remove the scrollview) and make it constrained to be on top of whatever views you don't want it to overlap (I assume the total_widget)



Unfortunately, I already tried that and it doesn't work. I removed the ScrollView and and put in the suggested constraint. I've updated my question with screenshots of the result.
